# Number of integral solution of $x+2y=n$ using generating function

Tags: generating-functions

I want to know, how to calculate the number of integral solutions of $x+2y=n$.

Comment: Are you restricting $x,y,n$ to be positive integers? Or non-negative integers? If they are unrestricted, then there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Yes , x and y are restricted to be only positive.

Comment: Then it is easy, there is one solution for each of $y=1,2,\dots,\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ or $\lfloor[\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ in total. [Note that $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor=n/2$ if $n$ is even and $(n-1)/2$ if $n$ is odd.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want positive integr solutions of  $x+2y=n$ is $y=1, x=n-2$ Check that  $x=n-2+2m, y=1-m$ then the condition that $x,y > 0$ implies that $-[(n-2)/2] < m < 1$, [.] denotes the integer part total number os solutions are $n/2-1$ if $n$ is even or $(n-1)/2$.

Comment: @DrZatarAhmedDSc $x,y$ are restricted to be positive, not non-negative

Comment: OK, now I have modified the solution for positive numbers.